# WSO2 Api Management Scalability

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Does anyone have any figures around the scalability of WSO2's API Management product please?

Number of concurrent users/API calls per second, data being transferred and how scalability was achieved in terms of deployment model.

Thank You,

Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to our LAB benchmark testings, Gateway node can handle ~3000 Transactions Per Second (TPS) when run with 150 concurrency in a 2 gateway node cluster. Please find detailed information of setup and performance test.

- Concurrency:   150
- TPS:         3000
- Response Time: 30

### Basic Setup Details

WSO2 API Manager : Gateway - 2 - active/active

WSO2 API Manager : Key manager - 2 - active/active

WSO2 API Manager : Publisher - 1 - active/passive

WSO2 API Manager : Store - 1 - active/passive

### Cache Settings

Gateway Cache enabled

### Hardware Settings

Physical :
3GHz Dual-core Xeon/Opteron (or latest), 4 GB RAM (minimum : 2 GB for JVM and 2GB for the OS, 10GB free disk space (minimum) disk based on the expected storage requirements (calculate by considering the file uploads and the backup policies) . (e.g if 3 Carbon instances running in a machine, it requires 4 CPU, 8 GB RAM 30 GB free space)

Virtual Machine :
2 compute units minimum (each unit having 1.0-1.2 GHz Opteron/Xeon processor) 4 GB RAM 10GB free disk space. One cpu unit for OS and one for JVM. (e.g if 3 Carbon instances running require VM of 4 compute units 8 GB RAM 30 GB free space)

EC2 : c3.large instance to run one Carbon instance. (e.g if 3 Carbon instances EC2 Extra-Large instance) Note : based on the I/O performance of c3.large instance, it is recommended to run multiple instances in a Larger instance (c3.xlarge or c3.2xlarge).

According to these results a single node can handle up to 3000 TPS. This TPS value can vary according to the concurrency level and load during the time. So when scaling we assume each node can handle up to 3000 TPS by which overall TPS will be increased.

Answer (score -2):

WSO2 API Manger has Throttling tier policy which allows you to limit the number of successful hits to an API during a given period of time.for example

1. **Bronze**: 1 request per minute
2. **Silver**: 5 requests per minute
3. **Gold**: 20 requests per minute
4. **Unlimited**: Unlimited access.

Please refer following links for more details about throttling policies 
[1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Enforce+Throttling+and+Resource+Access+Policies),[2](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Key+Concepts#KeyConcepts-Throttlingtiers).

Comment: I understand that I can throttle.  What I'm interested in here is the upper limit and what is needed to scale to reach this.